# Incorrect syntax near '<' error while tring to access ASP.Net variable from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

This fix possibly pretty easy. When I copy and paste it works, but my `SelectCommand` is too long and I need to get it from the code behind.

`Aspx` file:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_Dashboard" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$
                   ConnectionStrings:MyDbConn %>"
                   SelectCommand="<%= SelectCommand.ToString() %>">
```

`Cs` file:

```
public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string SelectCommand = "Select * from .....";
}
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the $ in `ConnectionString="<%$`?

Comment: @Despertar If I write my connection string directly to the selectcommand then it works so I didn't think that it is related to $

Comment: The '$' is black and not the expected red color.  Which is the point I think he was trying to make...

Answer (score 1):

You can set `SelectCommand` of `SqlDataSource` in code-behind's `Page_Load` instead of *aspx* file:

```
sds_Dashboard.SelectCommand = "Select * from .....";
```

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a constant newline in your code here:

```
ConnectionString="<%$ //HERE
                   ConnectionStrings:MyDbConn %>"
```

. But my concern is a little different, why can't you custom define your `select` statement in the window that looks like this:

[image]

Instead of in the code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your ASP.NET code into something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_Dashboard" runat="server" ConnectionString="<% ConnectionStrings:MyDbConn %>" />
```

Then from Code Behind, After some If/Else blocks, try this:

```
sds_Dashboard.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM ...";
```

It should work fine now.

Thanks.